# AsyncTask - How to pass value back to activity class after onPostExecute?

Tags: java, android

Here is my problem. I have created a asyncTask to link to my database and send and receive information using JSON.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    progressDialog.dismiss();
    returnValues = dataParsed.split("\\s+");

    mainActivity.getValue(this is the function that calls anotherfunction in 
    asyncTask)

    Log.v("ARRAY LENGTH", String.valueOf(returnValues.length));
}

public String[] returnmyString(){
    //return mySaveData;
    Log.v("ARRAY LENGTH 2", String.valueOf(returnValues.length));
    return returnValues;
}
```

I create the asyncTask object within my activity based class and then call that object.execute. My problem is that my code will continue to run once calling the object.execute and one of the lines calls a function within the asyncTask class before it is done executing all the code.

```
process.activitySave(1); //<---Process is the object for the asyncTask class
process.ContextSave(this,ServerURLSource,myParameters);
process.execute()
changedData = process.returnmyString(); //<-- this is the line of code that gets implemented that returns a null value
```

I have tried creating a Mainactivity object in the asyncTask class and then calling a function then that retrieves the value but my app crashes when I do this. any help would be appreciated. I would like to put some sort of listener in the mainactivity class as it seems I cannot reference any of the functions from my mainactivity class in my asyncTask class.

This is the function within the asyncTask to return the value:

```
public String[] returnmyString(){
    //return mySaveData;
    Log.v("ARRAY LENGTH", String.valueOf(returnValues.length));
    return returnValues;
}
```

Comment: You need a callback method. When task x is finished, pass the result to the activity using a method that takes the feedback as an argument

Comment: hey, could you further explain this type of functionality? task x would be the process.execute but what callback method would I use and where would I put it? And what kind of method would I use then to get the feedback?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply set your `changedData` into the `onPostExecute` @RW6 ? onPostExecute method runs on the same thread which you call #execute method.

Comment: Because I would still need a way to return that value from the asyncTask class to the MainActivity class unless there is something I'm just not getting.

Comment: you need an activity instance, and a public method in the activity. You pass arguments to the method (the result) and the method does whatever in the activity

Comment: If your AsyncTask implementation is in your Activity class, you can access to that Activities properties from that AsyncTask. You can set that changedData as `MainActivity.this.changedData = returnmyString()`in `onPostExecute`. If you implement AsyncTask as separated class, you need to pass callback handler to the async task.

Comment: and how would I create the callback handler to the asyncTask, my apologies for so many questions I am quite new to Java and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 is the basic, anonymous inner class implementation. Because of the inner AsyncTask class is not static class, you can access to the `CustomActivity`'s properties from that implementation.

In Method 2, AsyncClass implemented separately. If you gave your activity to this class, it can be call back your desired method after execution. This method, for our example is the #setChangedData method. CustomAsyncTask call backs the #setChangedData in the #onPostExecute.

```java
public class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String mChangedData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Method 1 - change data into the anonymously implemented AsyncTask class
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                CustomActivity.this.mChangedData = "foo"; // this changes mChangedData as "foo"
            }
        }.execute(1);

        // Method 2 - change data into the custom AsyncTask class
        new CustomAsyncTask(this).execute(2);
    }

    public void setChangedData(String changedData){
        this.mChangedData = changedData;
    }

    static class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
        CustomActivity mActivity;
        public CustomAsyncTask(CustomActivity activity) {
            this.mActivity = activity;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            mActivity.setChangedData("bar");
        }
    }
}
```

And, as method 3, if you want to separate you Activity and AsyncTask more loosely, this is the handler method:

```java
public class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String mChangedData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CustomAsyncTask task = new CustomAsyncTask();
        task.setOnDataChangedListener(new CustomAsyncTask.OnDataChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChanged(String data) {
                mChangedData = data;
            }
        });
        task.execute(1);
    }

    private static class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

        private OnDataChangedListener onDataChangedListener;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if(onDataChangedListener != null) {
                onDataChangedListener.onDataChanged("foo");
            }
        }

        void setOnDataChangedListener(OnDataChangedListener onDataChangedListener) {
            this.onDataChangedListener = onDataChangedListener;
        }

        interface OnDataChangedListener {
            void onDataChanged(String data);
        }
    }
}
```